# Run current py-file

Tags: python, elpy

Maybe I am wrong to think that `elpy` is or should be able to do that.

But can't I just run the current (means: open in current active buffer) `py`-file?

I read about <kbd>C-c</kbd> <kbd>C-c</kbd>. But this just open a new window with a python shell. But the file does not run automaticly.

I looked into emacs's menu bar and also there I could not find a hint how to "run".

There is a `if __name__ == '__main__':` in that file. And it is executable by filesystem.

Comment: The way I do this is by calling `python-shell-send-buffer`. You can probably bind it to something convenient.

Comment: And, if you wanted to run it from Dired buffer, you could move the point to it, and press `!`, then type `python`, for example.